# Name-calling: definition and technical name

Tags: meaning, expressions

What is the technical name and definition for name-calling? Examples, calling someone who has committed a crime a "monster", "predator", "perpetrator", "rapist"?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Are you limiting this to criminals, or just generally bad people?

Comment: You can just call it - [name-calling](https://www.google.com/search?q=name-calling&oq=name-calling&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: If the person _has_ committed the crime, the last two are just statements of fact. Terms like 'monster' could be called _invective_.

Comment: Perhaps "labeling"? Without further context, who knows?

Comment: Thank you. Assuming the person has committed a crime, I am questioning whether a term like perpetrator or rapist is actually "invective" as opposed to using language like "person who ___". Thank you for that word of "invective". Yes, name-calling and labeling appear to be applicable.

Comment: @Joan for that context "inflammatory language/terms" might be applicable too.

Answer (score 1):

One term for name-calling is given by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/pejorative) as

> **pejorative**
>   ADJECTIVE
>
> Expressing contempt or disapproval.
>
> *The individual may be classified as incomplete, immature, or by other pejorative terms which detract from his dignity.*

However, a **pejorative** term is not the same as name-calling, which can be a simple insult.
Describing a convicted rapist as a "rapist" is true.

Comment: Thank you for the comments that have been added. I question whether we can say "describing a convicted x as an x is true". Replace x with a word that no longer has a legal or medical basis for example. e.g. psychopath, witch, etc. Additionally, the word "rape" is not a legal word in some jurisdictions.